# Implementing Face Recognition using Local Descriptors (Unsupervised Learning)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, face-recognition, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to implement a face recognition algorithm using Python. I want  to be able to receive a directory of images, and compute pair-wise distances between them, when **short distances should hopefully correspond to the images belonging to the same person.** The ultimate goal is to cluster images and perform some basic face identification tasks (unsupervised learning).

Because of the unsupervised setting, my approach to the problem is to calculate a **"face signature"** (a vector in R^d for some int d) and then figure out a metric in which two faces belonging to the same person will indeed have a short distance between them.

I have a face detection algorithm which detects the face, crops the image and performs some basic pre-processing, so the images i'm feeding to the algorithm are gray and equalized (see below).

For the "face signature" part, I've tried two approaches which I read about in several publications:

1. Taking the histogram of the **LBP** (Local Binary Pattern) of the entire (processed) image
2. Calculating **SIFT** descriptors at 7 facial landmark points (right of mouth, left of mouth, etc.), which I identify per image using an external application. The signature is the concatenation of the square root of the descriptors (this results in a much higher dimension, but for now performance is not a problem).

[image]

For the comparison of two signatures, I'm using OpenCV's compareHist function (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html)), trying out several different distance metrics (Chi Square, Euclidean, etc).

I know that face recognition is a hard task, let alone without any training, so I'm not expecting great results. But all I'm getting so far seems **completely random.** For example, when calculating distances from the image on the far right against the rest of the image, I'm getting she is most similar to 4 Bill Clintons (...!).

[image: processed image with chosen facial landmarks]

I have read in [this](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/~verbeek/talks/EAFS.faces.Prague.sept.2015.pdf) great presentation that it's popular to carry out a *"metric learning"* procedure on a test set, which should significantly improve results. However it does say in the presentation and elsewhere that "regular" distance measures should also get OK results, so before I try this out I want to understand why what I'm doing gets me nothing.

In conclusion, my questions, which I'd love to get any sort of help on:

1. One improvement I though of would be to perform LBP only on the actual face, and not the corners and everything that might insert noise to the signature. How can I mask out the parts which are not the face before calculating LBP? I'm using OpenCV for this part too.
2. I'm fairly new to computer vision; How would I go about "debugging" my algorithm to figure out where things go wrong? Is this possible?
3. In the unsupervised setting, is there any other approach (which is not local descriptors + computing distances) that could work, for the task of clustering faces?
4. Is there anything else in the OpenCV module that maybe I haven't thought of that might be helpful? It seems like all the algorithms there require training and are not useful in my case - the algorithm needs to work on images which are completely new.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is unsupervised feature extraction - take a bunch of unlabeled images and find the most important features describing these images.

The state-of-the-art methods for unsupervised feature extraction are all based on (convolutional) neural networks. Have look at autoencoders (http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Autoencoders_and_Sparsity) or Restricted Bolzmann Machines (RBMs).

You could also take an existing face detector such as DeepFace (https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~ranzato/publications/taigman_cvpr14.pdf), take only feature layers and use distance between these to group similar faces together.

I'm afraid that OpenCV is not well suited for this task, you might want to check Caffe, Theano, TensorFlow or Keras.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have a Caffe framework that I would be able to use. Would you suggest developing a large training set of pre-processed faces, and running it through the CNN to obtain a better representation of each image, and then compute distances between images? Do you think that with a good enough representation, a simple Euclidean distance should be good enough?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was on my mind. If the features the CNN learns are good, a simple euclidean distance will be sufficient.