# Unsupervised Learning : Clustering based Facial Recognition

Tags: tensorflow, cluster-analysis, face-recognition, unsupervised-learning

I am able to do `supervised learning` for Facial Recognition with TensorFlow and especially after reading this great [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/building-a-facial-recognition-pipeline-with-deep-learning-in-tensorflow-66e7645015b8).  I highly recommend the tutorial even if you don't intend on running the code.

Does anyone know of an open sourced library that does [clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312759/implementing-face-recognition-using-local-descriptors-unsupervised-learning) of images based on facial recognition similar to `Google Photos` for instance?  Or even a tutorial with sample code?

I found a good [tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Autoencoders_and_Sparsity) on autoencoders, so building my own is an option, but I wanted to check if there's something open sourced, or some tutorial that has code I maybe able to `borrow`?

Comment: openface can do that. Why? Because it's CNN is learning a metric-embedding (euclidean) of faces. (did only skim through your clustering link, but that does not look like clustering!)

Comment: Similarity detection is probably more accurate than clustering.  But the end goal is to group the images by the person in the image

Comment: That's also covered by openface, as similarity is then the (inverse) distance in the metric-space.